# Wordpress add rewrite rule doesn't work for me

Tags: wordpress, plugins, url-rewriting, permalinks

I'm developing a plugin that creates 2 pages: one listing page and one details page.

I don't use custom types. I have created a table into the database where I save the company details and also a slug for the details page.

It's working properly but I have a problem with the URLs. They are not pretty.

On the listing page I use this code to create the link:

```
    <a href="https://www.website.com/company/details/?companyname=<?php echo $value->company_slug; ?>"><?php echo stripslashes($value->company_name); ?></a>
```

The generated link looks like this:

```
    https://www.website.com/company/details/?companyname=new-company-name
```

I use the query because I need it on the details page, where I use this code:

```
    $company_slug = $_GET['companyname'];
    $company_details = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table_company WHERE company_slug = '$company_slug'");
```

This is how I retrieve the company details from sql and it also works just fine.

I have created manually in Wordpress the details page.

The problem is that I want the details URL to look pretty, like this:

```
    https://www.website.com/company/details/new-company-name/
```

Generating it like this it's easy but when I click, I get a 404, since the query from URL is missing.

I was thinking it's easy to create directly the pretty URL and on the details page to parse the URL and get the company slug. It didn't work. I get a 404 maybe because the page doesn't physically exist.

So, I've done some research about URL rewrite and I have found some examples but none worked.

I have found tried this code also:

```
    add_filter('query_vars', function($vars) {
        $vars[] = "companyname";
        return $vars;
    });

    function custom_rewrite_rule() {
        add_rewrite_rule('^companyname/?([^/]*)/?','company/details/?companyname=$matches[1]','top');
    }
    add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

I've read that I shouldn't use matches if I use a custom URL instead of index.php, so I have also tried without matches:

```
    add_rewrite_rule('^companyname/?([^/]*)/?','company/details/?companyname=$1','top');
```

No results. If course, after every change I have saved again the permalinks.

This should be an easy task but somehow it doesn't work.

```
    https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/
```

Does anyone of you know how can I make this work?

Thank you.

Regards,
AG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the details page you created has the slug `company/details`. Here's what you need to do to make it work-

**1. Add the custom rewrite rules in functions.php file:**

```
function theme_custom_rewrites() {
    add_rewrite_tag("%companyname%", "([a-z0-9\-_]+)");
  add_rewrite_rule('^company/details/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=company/details&companyname=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'theme_custom_rewrites');
```

It registers a new rewrite tag/query var named `companyname` to be used later and registers a custom rewrite rule for the specific URL structure you want (`/company/details/company_name`).

**2. Get the company name on the template file and use it:** After you have added the above code and saved the permalinks, you can get the companyname just by using the `get_query_var()` function.

`$companyname = get_query_var( 'companyname' );`

Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your fast reply. It worked.

Of course, I had to change the link on the listing page to:

```
    <a href="https://www.website.com/company/details/<?php echo $value->company_slug; ?>"><?php echo stripslashes($value->company_name); ?></a>
```

I have removed the query from the link and it looks like this now:

```
    https://www.website.com/company/details/new-company-name/
```

What I don't understand, is how does WP know which is the query, since I removed it from the link.

I can see the same data if I access

```
    https://www.website.com/company/details/?companyname=new-company-name
```

or

```
    https://www.website.com/company/details/new-company-name/
```

But, basically, this part (?companyname=) doesn't exist anymore in the link, since I changed it.

I have no query now in my plugin, but somehow everything works properly. :)

I did not declare it somewhere. It's completely gone and it works.

How does this code know that the query exists and it's retrieving the slug from the database?

```
    $companyname = get_query_var( 'companyname' );
```

I only have this code now:

```
    <a href="https://www.website.com/company/details/<?php echo $value->company_slug; ?>"><?php echo stripslashes($value->company_name); ?></a>
```

So, no query in URL.

Thank you for your time.

Regards,
AG

Comment: It's working properly because of these two lines, `add_rewrite_tag("%companyname%", "([a-z0-9\-_]+)");` & `add_rewrite_rule('^company/details/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=company/details&companyname=$matches[1]', 'top');`.

Comment: Those two lines tell WordPress to match -`https://www.website.com/company/details/new-company-name/` and rewrite it to `https://www.website.com/index.php?pagename=company/details&companyname=$matches[1]`. Which in term loads the page with the slug `company/details` and sets up the `query_var companyname` to `new-company-name` which you can get just by calling `get_query_var( 'companyname' );`.

Comment: You can get a better understanding of how things are working here by going through the [WordPress Rewrite API docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API).

Comment: Also, if the answer solved your issue and if you don't mind, can you please upvote and accept my answer selected as well? TIA.